# CSS not linking to my form for some reason

Tags: html, forms, css3pie

I am trying to get a form styled with css on my webpage, but i cant seem to get the form to recognize the css.As you can see below I am simply trying to stlye the  element below is the code. Any thoughts? I am sure the solution is cake, new programmer over here.. any and all help is appreciated!

#### CSS

```
form {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, bottom, left 175px, from(#CCCCCC), to(#EEEEEE));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
  height: 450px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #09C;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: inset 1px solid #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

input {
  width: 375px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

textarea#feedback {
  width: 375px;
  height: 150px;
}

textarea.message {
  display: block;
}

input.button {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: #09C;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1p solid #999;
}

input.button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #09C;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #09C;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<form>
<div>
<h1>Contact Form :</h1>
<label>
<span>Your name</span><input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
</label>

<label>
<span>Email Address</span><input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
</label>

<label>
<span>Subject</span><input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" />
</label>

<label>
<span>Message</span><textarea id="feedback" name="feedback"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Submit Form" />
</label>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is the expected result different from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x40h8Ldh/2/)?

Comment: @devJunk I think you linked to the wrong fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/awgkc7rr/  But the question is the same... __What's the problem @Alex?__

Comment: thats exactly what the expected result should be.... the problem is, thats not what is showing on the page. It only shows the html, it acts like the css isnt even linking.
Here is the web address: http://leloupdevelopment.com/contact.html

Comment: i inspected the element in the website, it doesnt recognize that my CSS is even there. I'm lost.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it guys, i figured out my problem.. there was an open paranthesis sign near the bottom of the page. ugh! the little things